# How to install JRE fonts for java.lang.Error: Probable fatal error:No fonts found

Tags: java, spring

What should I do to install the fonts in JRE in spring?

```
2023-07-19 14:32:09,621 ERROR [org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter] (default task-3) Forwarding to error page from request [/simpleCaptchaImg] due to exception [Probable fatal error: No physical fonts found.]: java.lang.Error: Probable fatal error: No physical fonts found.
    at java.desktop/sun.font.SunFontManager.lambda$getDefaultPhysicalFont$0(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/sun.font.SunFontManager.getDefaultPhysicalFont(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/sun.font.CompositeFont.doDeferredInitialisation(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/sun.font.CompositeFont.getSlotFont(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/sun.font.CompositeGlyphMapper.initMapper(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/sun.font.CompositeGlyphMapper.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/sun.font.CompositeFont.getMapper(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/sun.font.StandardGlyphVector.init(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/sun.font.StandardGlyphVector.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Font.createGlyphVector(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: In modern Java, fonts are *not* necessarily bundled with the implementation of Java. Fonts are provided by the host OS.  See [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/intl/supported-fonts.html). Some vendors may choose to bundle fonts with their implementation of Java,  but such bundles are not required.

Answer (score -2):

Consider double checking your JDK settings and system environment. This error is related to your system or JDK. And another problem here if you are using Linux or Unix operating system, this error is very common.

Comment: I am not using Linux and Unix, how I can I know which fonts I am missing, thank you so much.

Comment: You should check your JDK for errors or not, if necessary, reinstall the environment, that's the only thing I know at the moment to fix that error.